# How to determine the count for substring in dynamic text?

Tags: c#, string, substring

ok so I have this string.

> Next: Warrant Officer Grade 2
>   21,202 / 33,000
>   21,202 / 33,000

It is a substring I have obtained from a long thing of text. Now "Warrent Officer Grade 2" as well as the numbers can be dynamic (I am loading these variables from a webpage) If there is a number in the ones or hundreds it does not append 0's so the exp for less than a thousand would look like "478" instead of 00,478.

Now my question is how to I obtain just "Warrant Officer Grade 2"? I already have this

```
int indexOfNext = myString.IndexOf("Next") + 6;  
//Below is what I need to obtain  
int count = 0;  
string newString = myString.Substring(indexOfNext, count);
```

But how would I help determine the **count** for getting the rank? or would It just be simple to create an array with all the ranks and the length of each rank?

Comment: Is the text actually on multiple lines? What is the line separator? What other text is present - could it contain "Next: " somewhere in the middle of a line? I suspect you'll want to split the text into lines before doing *any* of this...

Comment: How do I split it by lines? There is no character that I am aware of though that represents a line seperator

Comment: Well where did you get it from? If it's a file, there are methods which will do that very easily. Otherwise, if you *only* have it as a String, you could create a StringReader and call `ReadLine` for example... Basically, we need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression to search for the name and level for example

```
var regExp = new Regex(@"^Next: (?<name>[^\d]+) Grade (?<level>[\d]+)");
```

this will match all lines starting with `Next:` followed with the name, `Grade` word and level. The captured values of `name` and `level` groups can be retrieved later

```
var match = regExp.Match(input);
var level = match.Groups["level"].Value;
```

or modify it the way you want it.

Regex playground: [Derek Slager's A Better .NET Regular Expression Tester](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx)

Comment: I don't get it how to. I hate regular expressions, always made no sense to me. For instance, all I understand in yours is that it looks for "Next:" and "Grade".... Besides C# is not liking `new Regex`. it says **The type or Namespace `Regex` could not be found**

Comment: Ok so i got your code to work but it returns "2" and not the full rank. Why?

Comment: I need it to return "Warrant Officer Grade 2" not just the number or the rank name...

Comment: It's in `System.Text` namespace. You have to find the pattern, my says search for lines starting with `Next:` followed by one or more non-digits (`[^\d]+`), followed by `Grade` and the number is next (`[\d+]`).

Comment: I got it to return "Warrant Officer Grade" with **@"^Next: (?<name>[^\d]+)"** Why wont it return 2?

Comment: Because it is capturing only non-digit characters, try `(?<name>[\d|\w|\s]+)`, also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, otherwise I just used this code since it worked for my situation `string[] lines = NextRank.Replace("\r", "").Split('\n');` then just accessed `lines[0]`. But I'll look more into regular expressions. Btw does each modifier that u use in ur RegExp have to be enclosed in square brackets?